# How to convert object properties to list using linq?

Tags: c#, linq

Say there is a pair model that has a `FirstId` and a `SecondId` Guid property. I want to create a list of ids. Right now I am doing it like this:

```
var ids = new List<Guid> { };

payload.Pairs
    .ToList()
    .ForEach(x =>
    {
        ids.Add(x.FirstId);
        ids.Add(x.SecondId);
    });
```

Is there some magic method within linq that can do that instead of `ForEach`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `SelectMany`:

```
ids = payload.Pairs.SelectMany(p => new[]{ p.FirstId, p.SecondId }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Your approach could be translated to Linq's `Aggregate` function

```
var ids = payload.Pairs.Aggregate(
    seed: new List<Guid>(),
    func: (agg, item) => {
        agg.AddRange(new[] { item.FirstId, item.SecondId });
        return agg;
    },
    resultSelector: agg => agg);
```

If your `payload.Pairs` is already materialized and it is not an `IEnumerable` then you can do some memory optimisation like this

```
var ids = payload.Pairs.Aggregate(
    seed: new List<Guid>(payload.Pairs.Count * 2),
    func: (agg, item) => {
        agg.Add(item.FirstId);
        agg.Add(item.SecondId);
        return agg;
    },
    resultSelector: agg => agg);
```

[Here is a working example on dotnet fiddle.](https://dotnetfiddle.net/YasCEJ)

Answer (score 1):

Yet another type of solution could be to use two stream of guids

```
var firstIds = payload.Pairs.Select(item => item.FirstId);
var secondIds = payload.Pairs.Select(item => item.SecondId);
```

and then depending on the fact the ordering matters or not you can use `Zip` or `Concat` respectively.

```
firstIds.Concat(secondIds);
//OR
firstIds.Zip(secondIds, (f, s) => new[] { f, s }).SelectMany(x => x);
```

[Related dotnet fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Lv1Qwx)

Answer (score 0):

Alongside `SelectMany`, if you're looking to add them to an existing list, the `AddRange` function is the best to use:

```
ids.AddRange(payload.Pairs.SelectMany(p => new[] { p.FirstId, p.SecondId }));
```